# Query for multiple counts

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my DB called `Group`. There are 7 different groups (lets just say grp1-grp7).
Here is how I'm getting the Group count for grp1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total 
FROM db 
WHERE `Group`='grp1'
```

Is it possible to get the count of all 7 groups in 1 query?

Comment: Try to avoid using reserved words as table/column identifiers. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

You can use `group by` operator for grouping.

Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Group
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY Group;
```

Comment: var_dump is giving me all rows with a group entry: array(2) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(3) "179" ["Group"]=> string(0) "" } Is there any way to get 7 different counts?

Answer (score -1):

If the db is your database name, that wouldn't be correct. Here is how you need to structure your select query:

```
SELECT count(*), column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

In your case:

```
USE db;
```

The USE Statement is used to select a database and perform SQL operations into that database.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total 
FROM <table-name> 
WHERE `Group`='grp1'
```

Comment: I am using db as a placeholder for my actual schema.table

Comment: db stands for database and how can someone understand that you mean something else? Giving a - is so wrong in this case.

Comment: Because I said db in my question...next time I’ll spell out <table-name> instead of db so people like you don’t get confused